# java : Common pattern in public keys in RSA encryption

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa

I'm starting to notice that the public keys I generate in java have a common repetition or a pattern in the beginning and in the end when I print it.

These are the public keys that I generated and when I tried to print in string format they were in this form:

Here's the code I've used to generate the keys :

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(2048);
KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey pub = kp.getPublic();
PrivateKey pvt = kp.getPrivate();

byte[] encodedPublicKey = pub.getEncoded();
String b64PublicKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodedPublicKey);
System.out.println(b64PublicKey);
```

The first public key :

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAluBZlkmIH0GCt3z8B/y7PFECBKdlkRHZeGA/OOBOM/RNvBU+kyccN1TcDxeA/YmoOWUy8JuOj14Iv600mdmWAPUkm56w780o+7Ev8V9c6FLtyCcBI0bVknJTdGopaZRa1GgU11tivmBcPp6qpRodtVoBjBuWYatSDXyuso20yNGSm4muSsysFRsbpm236lmjk7T2nM8Rlv4LmjMlm63dhLJxCK2lB8guf7pCZFx/OPe32lXTBADx0Ci/DJfrgA1KhKVtzOttnS5/TfOLHIkfJ5CZj/oThQ/zfkc4Y5Qz/7XFz/KV9xeyZdKDVBMsf/Ib11X5w9pGmwlJUbeq08RqHwIDAQAB
```

And the second one :

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAiza6s7dpiMkh1T+W8bvgpbZXJxMm0W19PaDy2z1rEkjuIxOzp1WqVbEBrBWjiaH6HhN6sN60gTYxZF5mmRNFKQjc5ElOzY4/vnvi2NrUQpJudWR8SZetU0zFIurgUca7mM8WqMBOv6Blg8A25PfJrxDekmtbnAf3DFlRxvJTfqd6d4WAhVn1WoT9ce6DkRZJ8t73IgujcRlquVg2pTFO0wqN7xFzoQ70dPww243mQTzyJlcLmEkqAJi3xSyh8vFtgEM/jY1YwqQ5yjBqC1U55CiChuoNZ6g6obHC5G8sOOmWYr4dnDp2w8hNl7LssTexMOmCCd3cyue71FcsQk0LtQIDAQAB
```

What do these patterns mean and is it safe to have such patterns in the beginning of the public keys and do they pose a vulnerability?

Comment: You should show the code you are using to generate the keys.

Comment: Oops. Apologies, here is the updated post.

Comment: [ASN.1/DER encoding of key](https://www.google.com/search?q=asn.1+der+encoding+of+key) and [Abstract Syntax Notation One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) on Wikipedia.

Comment: For one, you should initialize your KeyPair with a SecureRandom, read this:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/step2.html

Comment: @jww ...or the old trusty javadocs :) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Key.html

Comment: What patterns are you referring to specifically?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice This sequence from the beginning : "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA", this sequence is common in all the public keys even if I initialize the keypair generator with secure random instance

Comment: I also see that a few of the right-most characters are also the same in the two examples you posted here.

Comment: Yes I did mention that in the post. Does it pose a vulnerability?

Comment: As @giorgiga pointed you to, the encoding for public keys used by Java (and defined by X.509) starts with data that identifies the algorithm of the key, in this case an 'OID' (object identifier) which is the same for all RSA keys; combined with the size being the same, this results in the DER encodings starting with the same octets. The last octets are similarly the same because all RSA keys generated by Java, and most other things today, use public exponent 65537 (the fourth Fermat prime, notated F4). Both of these are quite safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments: those keys are binary encodings of the public key. A public key consists of at least the modulus and public exponent, so some kind of structure is needed. For cryptography these components are often described using ASN.1 notation and encoded using BER/DER encoding.

Usually the ASN.1 BER encoding will quickly become different for different values as they contain length encoding. This is however not the case for RSA public keys as both the modulus and public exponent will always be the same size. Only the modulus is likely to change in value as it is unique for each key pair (if it is not then the random number generator is broken).

The public keys in Java are using the `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structures found in the X.509 certificate specifications. Advantage over the usual PKCS#1 encoding is that it contains an object identifier - *at the start* - indicating that it is an RSA public key. So this object identifier can be checked to make sure that it is indeed an RSA public key.

For a quick look at the structures please use `openssl -inform DER` after decoding the base 64. You can also use some online tool such as [this one](https://lapo.it/asn1js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to view the contents of the public key structure. Only use public and test keys for online tools, of course.

In general the value `30 8x` is the start of any ASN.1 structure with a significant size. The value `30` is a SEQUENCE which is usually required for a structure of multiple elements and the `8` is the start of the length encoding. So anything in base 64 starting with `MI` is likely encoded in ASN.1 BER/DER, as `MI` encodes the first 12 bits.